# How to upgrade mysql 5.5.46 to 5.5.50 in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am using mysql-community server in my ubuntu server (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.46, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)). During our recent vulnerability scan we got so many suggestion to apply CVE-2016-XXXX.
As per the suggestion from ubuntu site, I need to upgrade to 5.5.50 to resolve all vulnerability.
Please suggest the best practice to achieve this.

Comment: there is a security fix, don't worry, just `apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Should do the trick.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Oracle publish packages through their own (yum, apt) repos now. I would suggest going there for the most up to date versions and avoid being vulnerable due to Ubuntu lag.